# Show/hide div not working for textboxes-div in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 textboxes. Those are populating automatically as per Ajax data. I can confirm AJAX is working fine.

**Ajax Code**

```
$scope.formData.city1 = data.city1;
$scope.formData.city = data.city;
$scope.formData.city2 = data.city2;

if(formData.city1 != ''){
     $scope.secondcity1 = true;
}else {$scope.secondcity1 = false;}

if(formData.city2 != ''){
     $scope.thirdcity2 = true;
}else{$scope.thirdcity2 = false;}
```

Here the code to show/hide div.

```
formApp.controller('formProfile1', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.secondcity1;
    $scope.thirdcity2;      

    $scope.hidecity1 = function() {
        $scope.secondcity1 = false;
        $scope.city1 = ''; 
   }
   $scope.hidecity2 = function() { 
        $scope.thirdcity2 = false;
        $scope.city2 = '';
   }    

   $scope.showcity = function() { $scope.secondcity1 = true; }
   $scope.showcity1 = function() { $scope.thirdcity2 = true; }
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="firstcity">   
<div class="col-xs-10"><div class="topjob_resumetitle" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorcity }">
<input name="city" id="city" type="text" class="form-control textbox1 txt-auto" required="required" placeholder="Job Location* " ng-model="formData.city">
<div class = "errorba" ng-show="errorcity">{{errorcity}}</div>
</div></div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
</div>


<button type="button" class="addfields" ng-click="showcity()">+</button><br>
    </div>

<div ng-style="{'display':secondcity1 == false?'none':'block'">    

<div class="col-xs-9"><div class="topjob_resumetitle" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorcity1 }">
<input name="city1" id="city1" type="text" class="form-control textbox1 txt-auto" placeholder="Job Location* " ng-model="formData.city1">
<div class = "errorba" ng-show="errorcity">{{errorcity1}}</div>
</div></div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<button type="button" class="remove" ng-click="hidecity1()">-</button>
<button type="button" class="addfields" ng-click="showcity1()">+</button><br>
</div>

</div>

<div ng-style="{'display':thirdcity2 == false?'none':'block'"> 
<div class="col-xs-10"><div class="topjob_resumetitle" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorcity2 }">
<input name="city2" id="city2" type="text" class="form-control textbox1 txt-auto" placeholder="Job Location* " ng-model="formData.city2">
<div class = "errorba" ng-show="errorcity2">{{errorcity2}}</div>
</div></div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
<button type="button" class="remove" ng-click="hidecity2()">-</button>
</div>

    </div>
```

I tried ng-style and ng-show but both are not working. What I want is if data is coming from ajax then show respective textbox. If not then user can click on + button to show textboxes.

At the moment all boxes where ajax data is present visible but when I click on - to hide the boxes not working.

Below code is not working as expected with ng-show/ng-style.

```
 $scope.hidecity1 = function() {
            $scope.secondcity1 = false;
            secondcity1 = false;
            $scope.city1 = ''; 
        }
```

Comment: Move to Angular 4 already :P.  jk or may be not.

Comment: Is that the final code? In the ng-show directives, you are using some "errorcity" variables which are not managed in the controller..

Comment: Hi there. Just a note on titles - we prefer them to be in flowing English, rather than [to include home-made tag devices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495). If you can do that in the future, that would be great!